# Unable to close WebSocket with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sockets, safari, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to close my websocket via:

```
socket.close();
```

However I get the error on Safari 5.0.4:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'socket.close' [undefined] is not a function.
```

How can I properly close my web socket?

Comment: Run `console.dir(socket)` in Safari's developer tools. That will tell you what methods are defined on the `socket` object...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`socket.disconnect()` worked. yay.

Comment: I like that you returned to answer in case anyone else has the same question. You get an upvote :)

Comment: returning to answer is proper SO etiquette :)